# How to assign a property (not event) to an element that is created later, outside of NodeList?

Tags: javascript, element, nodelist, clonenode

- When we create the code that assigns this property from a similar element, we can call it as a method.
- This feature can be read continuously with the change event to the date input.
- I wanted to try something with MutationObserver, but it seems to me that it is no different from calling it as the method I mentioned at first.

```
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="date"/>
    </div>
    <button>Add</button>
```

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let clone = `<input type="date"/>`;
    document.querySelector('.inputs').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
})
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=date]').forEach(input=>{
  input.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
})
```

But apart from these, is there a method that we can run in a smoother dynamic structure?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion for this simple operation MutationObserver is too much expensive.

The main problem with your code, is that the `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=date]').forEach...` is not "reactive", but executed only once, at every script tag/file parsing.
Indeed for the first one input, added statically ( or server side ) in your html it works, but for the others added dynamically with the button it won't work.

So you must operate inside the `click` listener, like you did. But instead of simply create an html string you can create an `HTMLInputElement`
, set wathever property you want directly and append it.

```js
    const inputs = document.querySelector('.inputs');
    /**
     * We can create only once our `dateInput` prototype with all the attributes, 
     * and than clone it each time we need. ( You could use a clojure to, 
     * or put this 3 lines directly in the listener, but this should be a little more efficient)
     **/
    const dateInput = document.createElement('input');
    dateInput.type = 'date';
    dateInput.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
        inputs.append(dateInput.cloneNode()));
```

Now you have to manage the inputs which are yet in the page.

- If your view is rendered by a server script, you could simply add the max attribute there.
- If you want to add it via javascript, you can keep this line, and is going to work for multiple elements to:

```js
   document.querySelectorAll('input[type=date]').forEach( input => {
      input.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
   });
```

Working example:

```js
    const inputs = document.querySelector('.inputs');
    const dateInput = document.createElement('input');
    dateInput.type = 'date';
    dateInput.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
        inputs.append(dateInput.cloneNode()));
    
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=date]').forEach(input => {
        input.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="date"/>
    </div>
    <button>Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

--edit:
Another example, with more consistent date value:

```js
    const inputs = document.querySelector('.inputs');
    /**
     * We can create only once our `dateInput` prototype with all the attributes we need, 
     * and than clone it every time we need. ( You could use a clojure to, 
     * or put this 2 lines directly in the listener, but this should be a little more efficient)
     **/
    const dateInput = document.createElement('input');
    dateInput.type = 'date';
    
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        const newNode = dateInput.cloneNode();
        newNode.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
        inputs.append(newNode);
    });
    
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=date]').forEach( input => {
        input.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    });
```